# Compare date_time with today's date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I’m trying to compare a saved date_field with today’s date. Seems to work in console but I can't make it work in my code.

```
  <% @flights.each do |flight| %>
    <% if (Time.new("%Y-%m-%d") < flight.flight_date) %>
      <tr class="active">
    <% else %>
      <tr class="success">
    <% end %>
```

---

Thanks to @drenmi for the patient answers and explaining why that my date_field was saved as a datetime attribute hence `Time.now` working and not `Date.today`. 
Now to fix my naming so I follow convention!

Comment: So You always get class 'success' as a result, or comparing Time.new with date_field gives some error? Write the output of the flight.flight_date from the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Time.new("%Y-%m-%d")` will produce an empty `Time` object:

```
Time.new("%Y-%m-%d")
# => 0000-01-01 00:00:00 +0730
```

What you want to do is compare to `Time.now`:

```
<% if Time.now < flight.flight_date %>
```

Or, if using Rails, you might want to use `Time.current`, or `Date.current`:

```
<% if Date.current < flight.flight_date %>
```

or

```
<% if Time.current < flight.flight_date %>
```

Comment: I had tried Date.today however, it didn't work. Time.now on the other hand does! Thanking you!

Comment: I suspect that your "flight_date" field is actually a datetime field, rather than  date field, and that's why comparison with Time works and comparison with Date doesn't.  You should include this sort of information in your questions, since people looking at a column name "flight_date" would tend to assume it's a Date field.

Comment: my form is as follows:
`<%= f.date_field :flight_date %>`  - happy to change my Q but would appreciate some elaboration as I'm pretty new to ruby (and rails) @MaxWilliams

Comment: @IsabellaBrookes: A common naming convention is to name attributes that are datetimes with suffix `_at` (i.e. `flight_at`) and those that are dates with suffix `_on` (i.e. `flight_on`). :-) You can check in `db/schema.rb` if the attribute is a `date` or a `datetime`.

Comment: @Drenmi - thank you! That's really useful and now I am back on track mentally.

Comment: Don't use `Time.now`, instead I suggest `Time.zone.now`

Comment: @radubogdan: Good point. Changed the Rails specific part of the answer to use `current`.

Comment: @radubogdan and Drenmi: Very useful considering my project! Perfect! My table looks lovely now :D

Answer (score 2):

you want using `Date.today` in rails

Answer (score 0):

```
Time.now.utc
```

this is the best choice

time = Time.now.utc.iso8601

Time.iso8601(time)

...

don't forget: require 'time'